# How disable UDP transport in linphone android java code

Tags: android, sip, linphone

I have a problem in android linphone
I used TCP transport in linphone but
when I recieve SIP 302, TCP changes to UDP.
What should I do to handle this problem(preventing automatic change of SIP transport from TCP to UDP or disable UDP totally).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/org/linphone/core/LinphoneCore.html#setSignalingTransportPorts(org.linphone.core.LinphoneCore.Transports)) you should use the following piece of code to disable a specific transport:

```
Transports transports = LinphoneCore.getSignalingTransportPorts();
transports.udp = -1;
transports.tls = -1;
transports.tcp = 5060;
LinphoneCore.setSignalingTransportPorts(transports);
```

Notice that, there is a [similar question](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-xamarin/issues/2) related to iOS which uses 0 to disable a specific transport. However, [Android-documentation](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-xamarin/issues/2) mentions :

> negative value if not set

As a result you should use negative values as a way of disabling a specific protocol.